# Java Script Error Causing script to become unresponsive

Tags: java, javascript, web-applications

When I add the following Code to my html page for a java webapp, the script on the page quits responding. The snippet when removed below:

```
$("#btnCreateIng").click(function () {
    alert("clicked");
    var newName = document.getElementById("t_ingNameCreate").value;
    var newCategory = document.getElementById("t_ingCategoryCreate").value;
    var theData = "name=" + newName + "&" + "category=" + newCategory;
    alert("Sending: " + theData);
    var theUrl = "http://localhost:8080/webserv1/resources/ws2/ingredients/";
    $.ajax({
        url: theUrl,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        data: theData,
        success: function (result, status, jqxhr) {
            alert("success" + status);
            var ingArray = JSON.parse(result);
            alert(ingArray);
            var output = "<h3>Just Added</h3>";
            output += "<ul>";
            for (var i = 0; i < ingArray.length; i++) {
                output += "<li>" + ingArray[i].name + " (" + ingArray[i].id + "," ingArray[i].category + ")" + "</li>";
            }
            output += "</ul>";
            alert(output);
            $("#p_createIng").html(output);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, errorthrown) {
            alert("error" + status + " e: " + errorThrown);
            $("#p_createIng").html("Error:" + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    });
});
```

allows the script to actually run. I know the error derives from here but I can't pick out the error. Please help.

Comment: Please use at least basic indentation to make your code readable. (I've edited your code for you in this instance, adding spaces but not changing any of the actual text.) Anyway, I don't see how that code could slow down your page given that all it does is bind a click handler - the actual function wouldn't run until you click on the `#btnCreateIng` element.

Comment: Are you sure that the `java` tag is relevant here?

Comment: You have quite a few alert debuggers. How far does the code get through those? Do you get a response from the server? Or does it hang before then? I suspect an issue with contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"...

Answer (score 1):

```
output+="<li>" + ingArray[i].name+ "("+ingArray[i].id + "," + ingArray[i].category + ")"+"</li>";
```

You forgot one '+' sign. 
Of course, if this doesn't work after this syntax error fix - provide more details (check console).

Comment: wow thank you so much that was my error the entire time. Spent 3 hours trying to find that lol.